# R / Python / Assigning excels to different variables

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a list of many excel files:

```
files = ['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx',...]
```

and want to assign each of them to a **different** variable:

```
variables = ['a','b','c'...]
```

I want to get this:

```
a = pd.read_excel(file1.xlsx)
b = pd.read_excel(file2.xlsx)
```

I tried for loop and zip() but cant get anything:

```
for l, n in zip(variables ,files):
    l = n
```

I want to get result both in Python and R.

Comment: why not store then in dict or list like ,assign to environment will create problem

Comment: @YOBEN_S I did it too . I stored every pd.read_excel(file) in a list , but cant give them 'names' with variables

Comment: save it in dict ~ you can use the name as key

Comment: there are many files , is there any iteration method or I will to that by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, save assign the file in environment is not safe. Save it to `dict`

```
d={l:pd.read_excel(n) for l, n in zip(variables ,files)}
```

Then

```
d['a']
```

---

Not recommended solution `locals`

```
variables = locals()
for l, n in zip(variables ,files):
    variables["{0}".format(l)] = pd.read_excel(n)
```